# Nested ArrayList Object and Binary Search

Tags: java, search, arraylist, binary

If I have an ArrayList of an object that also contains another ArrayList as an element how can I declare it and initialize it at once and also how can I use binarysearch.
What I'm trying to do is initialize on 1 line without having to declare an arrayList of type obj2 and storing int on another variable.
For the binary search I'm over my head on that one.

```
import java.util.*;
public class nested{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    //im thinking something like this
    ArrayList<obj1> ex1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ex1.add(new obj1("exa1","exb1", new ArrayList<obj2> ) //this are giving me errors
    ex1.add(new obj1("exa2","exb2", new ArrayList<obj2> )
    ex1.add(new obj1("exa3","exb3", new ArrayList<obj2> )

    Collections.sort(ex1);
    int a = Collections.binarySearch(ex1,new obj1("exa1",null, new ArrayList<obj2>)) ;
    }

//obj1 class with 2 string elements and 1 arraylist of type obj2

public class obj1 implements Comparable
{
String a;
String b;
ArrayList<obj2> myobj2

public obj1(String a, String b, ArrayList<obj2> myobj2)
    {
     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
     this.myobj2 = myobj2;
    }
   public String geta(){return a;}
   public String getb(){return b;}
   public ArrayList<obj2> getmyobj2(){return myobj2;}
   public int compareTo(Object anB)
    {
    return getb().compareTo(((obj1)anB).getb());
    }
}

//obj2 class that stores a string
public class obj2 implements Comparable
{
String c;
   public obj2(String c)
   {
   this.c = c;
   }
   public String getc(){return c;}
    public int compareTo(Object myC)
   {
    return getc().compareTo(((obj2)myC).getc());
   }
}

public class Acomparator implements Comparator<obj1>
{
   public int compare(obj1 o1, obj1 o2)
   {
   return o1.geta().compareto(o2.geta();
   }
}
```

Comment: barapapupi, Your problem looks very similar to what it is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree.   Will you confirm?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you just missing the parenthesis at the end of the initialisation of the array lists? So you need this: `new ArrayList<obj2>()`

Comment: @GaryTsui I'm not sure what is B-tree sorry

Comment: @DanTemple Thank you, that fixes the initialization of arraylist of obj1 , for the binary search though I'm also trying this int a = Collections.binarySearch(ex1,new obj1("exa1",null,null)) ; and keeps giving me an error

Comment: @barapapupi Then I'd ask a separate question for that. This question is explicitly about the initialisation of your lists, not your issues with your binary tree. Also, if you're seeing an error, then it is useful to provide the error so that we can work out what might be going wrong.

Comment: @DanTemple sorry, I think i worded my response wrong. What i mean is that i want something like ex1.add(new obj1("exa1","exb1", new ArrayList<obj2>.add("test1"))) ;

Comment: In that case, the nicest thing to do is define a local variable and add the objects to the list, but if you really want to do it inline, then double brace initialisation will work, but is nasty to look at. Something like this: `new ArrayList<obj2>(){{add(new obj2("test1")); add(new obj2("test2"));}};` It is essentially extending the ArrayList class and running a static initialisation block that adds in the elements you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some paranthesis and a semicolon. Try this:

```
ex1.add(new obj1("exa1","exb1", new ArrayList<obj2>() ));
ex1.add(new obj1("exa2","exb2", new ArrayList<obj2>() ));
ex1.add(new obj1("exa3","exb3", new ArrayList<obj2>() ));
Collections.sort(ex1);

int a = Collections.binarySearch(ex1,new obj1("exa1",null, new ArrayList<obj2>() )) ;

public class obj1 implements Comparable<obj1>
{
String a;
String b;
ArrayList<obj2> myobj2

public obj1(String a, String b, ArrayList<obj2> myobj2)
    {
     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
     this.myobj2 = myobj2;
    }
   public String geta(){return a;}
   public String getb(){return b;}
   public ArrayList<obj2> getmyobj2(){return myobj2;}
   public int compareTo(obj1 anB)
    {
    return getb().compareTo(anB.getb());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the initialization of arraylist of obj1 , for the binary search though I'm also trying this int a = Collections.binarySearch(ex1,new obj1("exa1",null,null)) ; and keeps giving me an error

Comment: Even with parenthesis it gives me an error. It says no suitable method found for binarySearch(ArrayList<obj1>,obj1) and something with Method collections

Comment: obj1 needs to implement Comparable<obj1>. I updated my answer 1 more time.